# Inverted sawtooth wave problem

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

Is this correct, and does it repeat after 2pi?

Comment: This seems to be homework of some kind.  What work have you done so far on it?  You can get help here, but no one will do your work for you.

Comment: @JHStrom he already drew a graph

Comment: Also, please consider changing your tags. This has nothing to do with differential equations or Laplace transforms.

Comment: @mickep, it is under laplace transform problem in my practice paper.

Comment: @Heyo That doesn't mean the problem involves laplace transform.

Comment: You have drawn the right graph on the interval [0, $\pi $ ] what is your confusion with the other half?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. The function you graphed is not $\pi-t$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.

**Update**

Now it is correct. And indeed, it repeats (both to the left and the right).

Comment: the interval is 0≤t<2π, also what am I doing wrong? That is how the graph looks for π-t

Comment: What you do wrong? You do not graph the function $\pi-t$ on the interval $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. Do you understand what I mean by that?

Comment: 'You do not graph the function for ...' do you mean I am not suppose to draw for that interval or you meant ''You DID not graph the function for ...''

Comment: I mean that you did not draw the graph of $\pi-t$ in the interval $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.

Comment: @Heyo the latter. what is $f$ when $t = \dfrac{3\pi}2$?

Comment: @DHMO it's -pi/2, thanks a lot :3

Comment: @DHMO, I updated the original post, is it correct now?

Comment: @Heyo Yes it is.